# Google Chrome 54 Websocket Self-Signed Certificates

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, websocket

Apparently, chrome 54.0 does not work anymore with websocket towards my server which uses a self-signed certificate (secure websockets).
The console log keeps saying "Websocket failed, handshake was cancelled"
Does anybody confirm this?
I generated the certificate with

```
openssl req  -nodes -new -x509  -keyout server.key -out server.cert
```

Same, with a very long key:

```
openssl req  -nodes -new -x509  -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout  server.key -out server.cert
```

Comment: Here is a free alternative to self-signed certs using LetsEncrypt which is recognized as legit generally however I do not know if self-signed is the issue above            https://letsecure.me/secure-web-deployment-with-lets-encrypt-and-nginx/

Comment: Does the webpage where the websocket is created works under HTTPS using that same certificate?